# Calling a function of a spyk'd data class

Tags: mockk

I have a data class A with a function as follows:

```
data class A(val a: String) {
  fun foo(b: String) = "$a, $b"
}
```

I attempt the following mock in my test:

```
fun `whatever`() {
  val spy = spyk<A>()
  every { spy.a } returns "Tree"
  assertThat(spy.foo("Snake")).isEqualTo("Tree Snake")
}
```

When I run a test written like this it fails with a NullPointerException on the line **fun foo...** in the data class.

Am I doing anything wrong or is this a bug in MockK?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have totally different results when I run your code. Firstly it complains that there is no default constructor.

Then I fixed it to use the non-default constructor and it prints `"abc Snake"`

```
val spy = spyk(A("abc"))
every { spy.a } returns "Tree"
println(spy.foo("Snake"))
```

There is a reason for that. Kotlin is accessing `a` property through a field in `foo` function. This seems to be an optimization.

[image: getfield call]

MockK is not able to do anything about it right now. There is the following ticket to transform `getfield` call: https://github.com/mockk/mockk/issues/104